# How to set onChange handler to monitor changes in input fields that are rendered dynamically from an array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that contains an input field that is rendered dynamically from this array of objects.

```
const searchParams = [
    {
      name: 'certificateNo',
      title: 'Certificate Number',
      state: false,
      value: '',
    },
    {
      name: 'oldCertificateNo',
      title: 'Old Certificate Number',
      state: false,
      value: '',
    },
    { name: 'shareVolume', title: 'Share Volume', state: false, value: '' },
    { name: 'accountNo', title: 'Account Number', state: false, value: '' },
    {
      name: 'oldAccountNo',
      title: 'Old Account Number',
      state: false,
      value: '',
    },
    { name: 'rin', title: 'RIN', state: false, value: '' },
    {
      name: 'certificateIssueDate',
      title: 'Certificate Issue Date',
      state: false,
      value: '',
    },
    { name: 'clientName', title: 'Client Name', state: true, value: '' },
    { name: 'holderName', title: 'Holder Name', state: true, value: '' },
    { name: 'holderAddress', title: 'Holder Address', state: true, value: '' },
  ];
```

I'm rendering the input field using this code

```
<div className="search_inner_container">
                        {searchParams.map(
                          (item) =>
                            item.state && (
                              <Form.Item key={item.name} name={item.name}>
                                <Row className="search-row" align="middle">
                                  <Col span={7} style={{}}>
                                    {item.title}:{' '}
                                  </Col>
                                  <Col span={17}>
                                    <Input
                                      style={{
                                        background: '#FFFFFF',
                                        borderBottom: '1px solid grey',
                                      }}
                                    />
                                  </Col>
                                </Row>
                              </Form.Item>
                            ),
                        )}
                      </div>
```

The input fields are only rendered when state is true. What I need to do is to make an onChange event to monitor the changes in the input field.  Any ideas on how to that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want but if you need to add the value of the input to the array of object you need to do like that but it's better to make the array of object in a useContext or useState hooks.

```
<div className="search_inner_container">
  {searchParams.map(
    (item, index) =>
      item.state && (
       <Form.Item key={item.name} name={item.name}>
        <Row className="search-row" align="middle">
          <Col span={7} style={{}}>
             {item.title}:{' '}
          </Col>
          <Col span={17}>
            <Input
              style={{
               background: '#FFFFFF',
               borderBottom: '1px solid grey',
              }}
             onChange={(e)=>{searchParams[index].value = e.target.value }}
           />
         </Col>
      </Row>
   </Form.Item>
    ),
    )}
</div>
```